# Replacing quotes in a html input

Tags: html, razor, double-quotes, html-input, single-quotes

I've got some strings coming through a Model and am making html inputs from them. More or less as below:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<dynamic>
@{
    this.Layout = "Views/Shared/Bootstrap.cshtml";
}
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" value='@if(this.Model.Model.Description != null)
{
    @this.Model.Model.Description.Replace('a','b')
} ' />
```

Which is all well and good. I've managed to get the replace a with b in there (the code I've inherited isn't the most stable of things) and that works, just as an example.

As you may well have gathered, we're having issues with quotes. Some users will have entered things like:

> Sam's little brother said "I don't like apples".

Which of course means that our input becomes:

```
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" value='Sam's little brother said "I don't like apples".' />
```

Meaning that the only thing that gets rendered is

> Sam

Edit - Vikas' answer gave me...

```
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" value="@if(this.Model.Model.Description != null)
{
    @this.Model.Model.Description.Replace("&#34;","&#quot;")
} " />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double quotes instead of single quotes ("") as shown below:

```
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" value="Sam's little brother said &#34;I don't like apples&#34;." />
```

Comment: Tried that. Then we only get "Sam's little brother said "

Comment: Is there a way to get one lot of quotes (either single or double) replaced with &quot; - tried replacing a with &#39; (I think it was) and Razor threw a hissy fit.

Comment: try html entity number (&#34;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Html.Raw` and ternary operator to show single quotes and double quotes like this:

```
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" 
       value="@Html.Raw(this.Model.Model.Description != null ?
              @this.Model.Model.Description.Replace('a','b') : "")" />
```

The above code will generate HTML markup like example below:

```
<input id="ModelDescription" type="hidden" value="Sam's little brother said &quot;I don't like apples&quot;.">
```

**Note:** Better to use `@Html.HiddenFor()` instead manually setting `value` attribute like that.

Demo: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)